# React redux and initializing props with asynchronous action resolution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I m learning redux and react and I'm having a little problem concerning good practices of props initialization.

In fact, I m having a route that looks like following :

```
/pokemons/:name
```

And here's the concerned component :

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {showDetail} from './../../redux/modules/pokemons';

export class PokeDetail extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.currentPokemon.name}
      </div>
    )
  }

}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  currentPokemon:state.pokemons.currentPokemon
});

export default connect((mapStateToProps),{
  showDetail
})(PokeDetail);
```

The fact is that I don't know at all **when / where** to send my action to change my app state. In fact, when should I send my "showDetail('myPokemonName')" so that the currentPokemon state would change and my app work ?

I m needing some good practices if possible

Thanks for your help

EDIT :

```
My PokeView :

import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {loadRemoteAction} from './../../redux/modules/pokemons';
import {Link} from 'react-router';


export class PokeView extends React.Component {
  render(){
    let i = 0;
      return (
        <div>
        <h4>Super page</h4>
        <button onClick={this.props.loadRemoteAction}>Start</button>
        <ul>
        {
          this.props.pokemons.map(item => {
            i++;
            return <li key={i}><Link to={`/pokemons/${item.name}`}>{item.name}</Link></li>
          })
        }
        </ul>


        </div>
      );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  pokemons : state.pokemons.pokemons
});


export default connect((mapStateToProps), {
  loadRemoteAction
})(PokeView);
```

My action / reducer :

```
import immutable from 'immutable';

/**
 * Action part
 */
export const LOAD_REMOTE = 'LOAD_REMOTE';
export const SHOW_DETAIL = 'SHOW_DETAIL';

export function loadRemoteAction() {
  return dispatch => {
    fetch('http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => dispatch({
      type:LOAD_REMOTE,
      payload:res.results
    }));
  };
}

export function showDetail(name){
  return {
    type:SHOW_DETAIL,
    payload:name
  }
}

/**
 * Reducer part
 */


const ACTION_HANDLER = {
  [LOAD_REMOTE] : (state, action) => {
    if(action.payload) return Object.assign({},state,{pokemons:state.pokemons.concat(action.payload)});
    return state;
  },
  [SHOW_DETAIL] : (state, action) =>{
    let  currentPokemon;
    for(const pkm of state.pokemons){
      if(pkm.name === action.payload) currentPokemon = pkm;
    }
    if(action.payload) return Object.assign({},state,{currentPokemon:currentPokemon});
    return state
  }
}


const initialState = {pokemons:immutable.fromJS([]), currentPokemon:immutable.fromJS({name:''})};
export default function pokemonReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  const handler = ACTION_HANDLER[action.type]
  return handler ? handler(state, action) : state
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, an action is when something happens in the world - this would usually either be something a user does, or e.g. an asynchronous answer from the backend to an ajax call. These are the situations in which you would want to send an action (containing the information about what was changed) so that your state tree can be updated accordingly.
In your case, if you show a list of Pokemons somewhere else on the screen, and the user clicks on one of them, then that click would save the clicked-on Pokemon to the state tree, and your `PokeDetail` component would then pick up this information and display the details for the selected Pokemon.

In your case, the `PokeView` render function might look like this:

```
export class PokeView extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Super page</h4>
        <button onClick={this.props.loadRemoteAction}>Start</button>
        <ul>
        {
          this.props.pokemons.map((item, i) => <li key={i}><button onClick={this.props.dispatch(showDetail(item.name))}>{item.name}</button></li> )
        }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and the `PokeDetail` class might look like this:

```
export class PokeDetail extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return <div>{this.props.currentPokemon.name}</div>;
  }
}
```

The other question is, how does the information go into my app initially? If the data is static, you can add it to your initial state tree (one usually passes that to the reducer function as default parameter), or you could query the data from the backend via an Ajax call. The latter can be done in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method of your component. (For this, you need `redux-thunk` in order to have an action that works together with the callback and the asynchronous answer from the backend).

Comment: I actually load the list from a remote API and it works well. The fact is just that I can't load initial props inside of the detail page (the pokemon is already loaded inside of the state tree in a list, I get it inside of the reducer and change the state tree with the actual selected pokemon) But I need to get it when I change the page

Comment: Hm, I don't exactly understand what you are trying to do, but I just noticed that you may want to use `{this.props.currentPokemon.name}` in your render function?

Comment: Exactly. From the beginning : I make an async action to get a list of pokemons. When I click an item of this like, I m redirected on /pokemons/:name, on another component. The fact is that the new component has to know who is the currentPokemon in the state tree to display his information. And I dont know how to pass the result of the "SHOW_DETAIL" action (which has to find the good pokemon inside the list and put it in the currentPokemon state object).

Comment: Like I said in my answer: In your case, if you show a list of Pokemons somewhere else on the screen, and the user clicks on one of them, then that click would save the clicked-on Pokemon to the state tree, and your PokeDetail component would then pick up this information and display the details for the selected Pokemon. Then there is no need for the showDetail function any more.

Comment: The fact is that I don't know where my PokeDetail should get this information. I mean in which function ? Render is immutable so I don't know :-/

Comment: If you add the code of your other component and of your reducer to your question, I can modify it to show you what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You should call **showDetail** action in componentWillMount function.

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {showDetail} from './../../redux/modules/pokemons';

export class PokeDetail extends React.Component{
  componentWillMount() {
    // If you are using react-router, route params will be in `params` property object.
    const pokemonId = this.props.params.id;
    this.props.showDetail(pokemonId);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // Also you may want to update your component when url was changed.
    if (nextProps.params.id !== this.props.params.id) {
      this.props.showDetail(nextProps.params.id);
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.currentPokemon.name}
      </div>
    )
  }

}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  currentPokemon:state.pokemons.currentPokemon
});

export default connect((mapStateToProps),{
  showDetail
})(PokeDetail);
```

When your component is mounting(or updating), you are calling your action with pokemon id. Next your store will be updated and you will receive needed props in PokeDetail component.

Also for async actions you may need [redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk) package.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [redux-async-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-async-connect) package. You can find sample usage of this package [here](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/containers/Widgets/Widgets.js).